# No puedo conectar los servicios de Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

Instale `Oracle` en `Ubuntu 18`, pero despues de seguir una guía no me conecta a los servicios y me muestra:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ale-VirtualBox)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                04-JUL-2018 11:51:40
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 14 min. 29 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ale-VirtualBox/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Claudio-VirtualBox)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Cual es el error? De lo que se ve que no tiene servicios, puede ser que la BD no este arriba o la configuracion del listener no esta bien.

Comment: volver a instalar?